# Android Webview - Resize image if too large

Tags: java, android, image, webview, image-resizing

I am writing an Android application in Java, which basically functions as a forum reader for a private forum. The app displays a list of threads and once the user chooses a thread, a new Activity is opened that basically consists of a single WebView. The app downloads and parses the source (html) of the forum thread and then returns a list of 'post' items that contain just the required information (eg author, contents as html, etc). Finally, I simply build some HTML from that list of posts and display it in the WebView.

While this is working absolutely fine, there is a problem with images: sometimes the images are very large and the user has to scroll both horizontally and vertically to see the whole image. I would like to resize these images to the width of the WebView (so that they are always fully visible), with optionally turning them into a hyperlink that opens the full size image.

Since I am parsing the thread HTML myself, I could in theory take each img tag and add a "width=100%" attribute to it. The problem then is that small images (such as emoticons!) are also resized and blown up very large. I only want to resize images that are too large to display on the device.

How can I achieve this? Some methods that I can think of (but not quite reach the desired solution with) are of course:

- Modifying the HTML of the post content before displaying it in the WebView,
- Changing the CSS stylesheet that the WebView uses to display the post content
- Adding javascript to the WebView source

Basically I have complete access to the HTML, CSS and Javascript, and still I cannot figure out how to resize images that are too large (but not images that aren't too large).

Zooming is not an issue as it is disabled for this WebView.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the view port within your HTML file?

Below there is an example of how you may achieve that, for high-density, medium-density and low-density devices you are able to set the parameters such as minimum-scale, maximum-scale etc.

```
function setViewPort() {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

    //high-density screen
    if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1.5) {
        viewport.setAttribute("content", "target-densitydpi=high-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.15, minimum-scale=1.15, maximum-scale=1.8" );
    }
    //medium-density screen
    else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1.00) {
        viewport.setAttribute("content", "target-densitydpi=low-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.3, minimum-scale=1.3, maximum-scale=1.3");
    }
    //low-density screen
    else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 0.75) {
        viewport.setAttribute("content", "target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, height=device-height, maximum-scale=1.3");
    }}
```

Check also the Android Doc [Targeting Screens from WebApps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html)

Comment: This is very useful information, however it does not really answer the question.  This will scale the page as a whole to better fit the target screen resolution, but still does not solve the problem of images that are larger than the viewport. A CSS max-width is probably best for that.